# Unable to print from Visual Basic running in WINE?

Tags: wine, printing

I'm new to Ubuntu and I have installed Microsoft Visual Basic using WINE but I am unable to print to lp0. I am using the following code:

```
open "/dev/lp0/" for Output As #1
```

In Windows I used to use the following:

```
open "Lpt1:" for Output As #1
```

This has worked for years in Windows. Tried both in Ubuntu and I get a runtime error 75.

Other programs can print with no problem. Checked printer device URI:parallel:/dev/lp0, access control allow printing for everyone. Even the VB6 complier can print. What am I missing?

Comment: Visual Basic is for Windows. How are you running the program exactly, in Ubuntu?

Comment: I installed VB with WINE, the VB complier works fine. The program I am having problem with printing works except for printing.

Comment: Please update your question with that information.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open system devices from a Windows program under `wine` in this way. You must use the Windows APIs to interact with the system.

You will need to configure wine to be able to print. The [Wine user Guide](http://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/misc-things-to-configure) includes information on how to configure printers.